# passing integers in place of file descriptor when calling write command in c

Tags: c

```
void main()
{

     pid_t  pid;
     int    i;
     char   buf[BUF_SIZE];
     fork();
     pid = getpid();
     for (i = 1; i <= MAX_COUNT; i++) {
          sprintf(buf, "This line is from pid %d, value = %d\n", pid, i);
          write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
        // printf("%s",buf);
     }
}
```

I've got the given simple code to show fork process in c. I noticed that when I pass any value greater than 2 in place of 1 in write command the code does not print anything. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should check the `return` value of `write` for an error.

Comment: 1 is for standard output descriptor, 2 is for error. Others aren't open

Comment: note that the `fork` part is irrelevant to the question. The example could be reduced even more to only include a `write` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're performing a raw `write` call where at the start of your program:

- 1 is the standard output descriptor
- 2 is the standard error descriptor

Both write to the console by default (and 0 is the standard input, cannot be written to)

Other descriptors are invalid unless they've been returned by an `open` call. Since you don't check the return value of `write`, you can't see that an error code is returned (probably `EBADF`, bad file descriptor)